# How to control page order for category links

Tags: link-category

Is there any way (including any plugins) to control the ordering of pages within a category link? I cannot find any way to change from "published date" descending. I would prefer to manually set the order on these listings, as some swarm removal beekeepers are more active and available than others.

Here's a page on our website that I would like to re-order: https://www.gilroybeekeepers.org/category/swarm-removal/santa-clara-county/. The links on this page, e.g. "Gilroy" has a link: "https://www.gilroybeekeepers.org/category/swarm-removal/santa-clara-county/gilroy/".

Answer (score 0):

The built-in solution to change the order of posts in a category is to change the "Order" attribute of each post. If your post type is set to support "Post Attributes", you should have a box that looks like this in your right sidebar when editing the post:

[image: Post Attributes Box]

0 will be the first in the list, and ordered in ascending numerical value. Note that this will change the order of wherever your posts are displayed on your website, not specific to a single category page.

Comment: Questions about plugin recommendations are off-topic here so I'm not including it in my answer, but one I've used that gives a much more intuitive interface is "Post Types Order". It lets you drag and drop posts in whichever order you like.

Comment: I've tried changing the page order, and it did not work. Everything appears to be locked down on sorting pages within a category *strictly* by Publish Date descending. Could this issue be something locked down in the theme in use (IXION), or some global site setting?

Comment: If this doesn't work, then likely there is somewhere in your theme code that is preventing the "Order" value from having an effect. The default if no sorting value is specified is `publish_date`, but if `publish_date` is set as the sorting option, then the "Order" value won't matter.

Comment: Check your theme files for a `category.php` file (making sure to create a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#create-a-style-css) if you plan on making any changes). Then search for a `get_posts()` or `WP_Query` query, and an argument array associated with it. Check that array to see if there exists a `'order_by' => 'date'` parameter and remove it. If you need further help than that, I'd recommend contacting the theme developer as theme support is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Controlling the order of pages within a category link on a WordPress website is usually done using a custom order or a plugin that allows manual ordering. Here are some solutions:

**1. Page Features in WordPress:**

- Make sure your theme supports custom page templates.
- Edit each page under "Swarm Removal" and set the "Order" property in the "Page Properties" box.
- Update pages in the desired order.

**2. Plugins:**

- Install a plugin that allows for custom ordering of pages. One such popular plugin is Simple Page Ordering.
- Install and activate the plugin.
- After activation, go to "Pages" in your WordPress admin menu.
- You should see a new column labeled "Order" where you can set the order of your pages manually.

**3. Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order:**

- Another plugin you can try is Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order.
- Install and activate the plugin.
- Visit the plugin settings and configure the order for your categories and their respective pages.

**4. Custom Code:**

- If you're comfortable with coding, you can implement custom queries in your theme files or use hooks to modify the ordering. This requires knowledge of PHP and WordPress development.

**Important Note:**
Always make sure you have a backup before making changes to your site, especially when using plugins or custom code.

Choose the solution that best suits your needs and technical expertise. If you're not comfortable with coding, the easiest way to achieve manual ordering of pages is to use plugins like Simple Page Order or Category Order and Taxonomy Terms Order.

Comment: Neither 1 nor 2 appear to be working... I've previously tried changing the page order, and it did not work. Everything appears to be locked down on sorting pages within a category strictly by Publish Date descending. The Simple Page Ordering plugin is nice, in that you can just drag the posts into order, but it appears to be simply updating the "page order", which as per above is NOT influencing the ordering. I have not tried #3 yet, and not sure I want to give 4 a shot. Could this issue be something locked down in the theme in use (IXION), or some global site setting?